# What's the best way of implementing from_iterable alternate c-tor?

Tags: python, class

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

I started with code like this:

```
class Base(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return super().__new__(cls, args, **kw)

class Usual(Base):
    pass

class Optimized(Base): # optimized to case with 2 arguments
    def __init__(self, *_, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        if len(self) != 2:
            self.__class__ = Usual
```

I decided it would be nice to add `from_iterable` c-tor to the `Base`, like `itertools.chain`'s one.
I couldn't however find `chain`'s implemented in Python in PyPy's source, so I decided to find out own solution.

## Approach 1 — starred expression

```
@classmethod
def from_iterable(cls, iterable):
    return cls(*iterable)
```

The first I've thought about. Simple, readable, pythonic. However, I *belive* that starred expression is expensive, so I avoid unnecessary ones if it doesn't make code more flexible.

## Approach 2 — `super().__new__`

```
@classmethod
def from_iterable(cls, iterable):
    obj = super().__new__(cls, iterable)
    obj.__init__()
    return obj
```

Instead of using modified `Base.__new__`, uses `tuple.__new__`, which constructs  instance based on iterable. Works nice, but worries me about the `__init__` – it receives positional arguments passed to `__new__` if object is crated by calling a class, but receives no positional arguments (except `self`) when object is created by `from_iterable`. This inconsistency is not a problem, because `__init__` ignores them anyway, but I'm affraid that overriding `__init__` in subclass could lead to subtle bugs, pretty hard to trace.

I could write `obj.__init__(*iterable)`, but then this solution is worse than previous – more complicated, less readable, and still with starred expression I wanted to avoid.

## Approach 3 — metaclass

```
class WithFromIterableCtor(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args):
        return super().__call__(args)
    def from_iterable(self, iterable):
        return super().__call__(iterable)

class Base(tuple, metaclass=WithFromIterableCtor):
    pass

class Optimized(Base):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        if len(self) != 2:
            self.__class__ = Usual
            # self.__init__() # Usual has no __init__
        else:
            super().__init__()
```

This is the solution I decided to use. I wrote simple metaclass to alter creation of instances. It takes care of the problem in encapsulated way. It also avoids starred expression.

However, it makes class confusing: `__init__` definition suggest that it takes iterable, but to create a instance you pass variable number of arguments... Also, isn't using metaclass overkill here?

**Is there any better approach I am missing? If no, which soultion is better – 1st or 3rd?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (the metaclasse way)is obvioulsy **not** the "one and obvious" way of doing it. 
In general when, in "Python talk" we talk about the "one and obvious" way it is the simplest way (even when it is possibly not the most performant). On these examples you went way, way, way out of simplicity just because you did assume ("believed" in your words) that the starred call would be "expensive".
Well, it is not. But even it was, the gain on the workarounds would likely be negligible.

In Python there are other sayings beyond "the one obvious..." - one of them is "premature optimization is the root of all evil". And if one phrase on "python lore" applies to the above listings, this is the one with the best match by far.

IF - and IF - after getting your project working, you'd decide that there was time and need for some optimization, then you could resort to using a profiler, and check if one of the other methods would give you some gain (hint: most likely not - the "star" packing/unpacking or argument above is done in native code; the twirls and turns you take with your metaclass approach just add one layer of indirection and would hardly show up in profiling either) . However, the maintenance burden you add by using the metaclass approach if definitely far from light.  I am usually considered a "big" metaclass user and proponent, and I have to stare hard at what you are doing there (and it just looks like it is a big no-op). (Besides, it will hide the `from_iterable` from ordinary introspection on instances of your classes - not usually expected).

There is another huge anti-pattern above which is changing the instance class upon initialization. Now, that, if you really want it, should be lie on  `__new__`, or, maybe, that would be a suitable use for a metaclass. In other words, just to be clear: choosing the created instance class based on the input should be done on the metaclass or on the new method rather than `__init__` *if* you are doing that.

But much better than either is to have an ordinary function to work as an instance factory: this function instantiates objects of the proper class based on the parameters received:

```
def MyUbberTuple(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) == 2:
        return Usual(*args)
    return Optimized(*args)
```

Comment: Thank you. Factory function seems neat. Also, with it, I could take `iterable` in ctor, and `*args` in factory. And about optimization, now I'm rethinking if I really need `Optimized` class.